# X-Cart Run Ajax On Successful Order

Tags: jquery, ajax, x-cart

I have an X-Cart store, when a person places a successful order I would like to send an ajax request to the server using jquery (if possible), or at the very least run some PHP code at that point.

Does anyone know where in the x-cart file structure the code is to do something like this?

UPDATE: I am using the One Page Checkout Module for checkout.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The files I needed were in includes/func/func.orders.php ..    Since its already PHP, no need for an ajax call, just coded what I needed directly into the order complete function.   There are also functions for order placed and order processed if you need to put something there.